# How to modify the display of custom line items in the ADD To Cart Form?

Tags: commerce

My issue is this, imagine that I have created a few custom line item types in [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) called:

- Text on TShirt FRONT
- Text on TShirt BACK

I use these two fields in the ADD To Cart Form checkbox so that the customer can specify what the want on the fron of the Tshirt to say and the back. So far so good.

The issue is that how do I change the display of this product node so for example I don't want it to appear in a single column but in two columns side by side.

I have tried [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels), I have tried [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds), this is not working. I can't even change the order of fields say I wanted the back to show up first and then the front.

I have tried changing things around in line item configuration display, which doesn't work and I have also tried changing the disply of the product display content type, (which btw does not even show the individual fields of the add to cart forms).

I am not good with coding so I would appreciate if I can work on this from the front end with any modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional fields directly to the 'add to cart' form on a per item basis with the help of the [Commerce Customizable Products](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) module. This allows you to create additional custom line item types. When you create the field there is a checkbox under ADD TO CART FORM SETTINGS that will add these fields to the add to cart display.

Comment: I did add the fields using Commerce Customizable Products.  The question is not how to add fields, the question is how do you format the display of these custom fields in the product display content type.  For example how can two custom fields be displayed to show in two columns side by side?

Comment: Is CSS an option? You could just float the fields next to eachother if you already have the fields on the page.

Comment: That's an idea, but where to inject the CSS from the front end?